# Python Requests: How to set optional and non-optional parameters at the same time?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to query my database with an API.

I have:

```
import requests
query_params = {'author':'grisham','year':'1998'}
response = requests.get(url='http://111.111.1.1:1000',params=query_params)
```

This works fine, I can return a data frame of all the books with author grisham published in the year 1998.

However, I want to amend this to say 'author is a compulsory parameter, but the year may optionally be added as a second parameter' (to differentiate for those who just want all his books, versus those who want to know what he published in one particular year).

I can't seem to find in the requests library, instead of params, can i change this to two dictionaries, optional and compulsory params, and pass them in separately? Or is there a better way to do this?

I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282018/pass-optional-parameters-to-http-parameter-python-requests) is sort of what I'm looking for, wondering if there is something more pythonic/efficient/cleaner for my use case?

Comment: requests doesnt know anything about the conditional parameters of the API its just passing what ever you tell it. so if you dont want to send year then just dont add it as a parameter

Comment: If you want to enforce any constraints on the data, you need to provide your own wrapper around `requests.get`, rather than using it directly. A subclass or or wrapper around `PreparedRequest` is also a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a given parameter is required or not, and (if not required) whether you choose to include it in a call to the API makes no difference to the `requests` library. It's job starts and ends with sending the data you give it and reporting the result. Whether year is required should be included in the API specification. If it is optional, then you can choose to leave it out by simply not including it in the dictionary you send.

Put another way, the `year` field is a parameter that to the API. It isn't a parameter to the `requests` library, and `requests` only knows or cares about it to the extent that it's a piece of data that is needs to send in the body of the request. To `requests` the year field is *always* optional, because `requests` is just passing a message along.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, it's up to you to validate the provided parameters to decide whether any required parameter is correctly passed in. The `requests` library is only sending it out.

And yes, you can pass two dictionaries into `requests.get()` (requires Python 3.5+):

```py
query_params = {**required_params, **optional_params}
```

Comment: That's not really passing 2 dictionaries to `requests` though... it's just unpacking them into a single dictionary and giving the result to `requests`. It's definitely compact and effective use of syntax, but doesn't actually do what you claim.